# Running a batch script remotely using rdesktop

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, file-sharing, rdesktop

I have a setup that implies calling **rdesktop** on a remote machine which is accessed through ssh:

```
user@192.168.1.110:~$ ssh user@192.168.1.120 -X
```

and then running **rdesktop** as:

```
user@192.168.1.120:~$ rdesktop 192.168.2.130 -u username -p password -r disk:local="./TestRDP" -s "cmd.exe /K net use C: \\\\tsclient\local & C:\\test.bat & logoff"
```

On the machine that **rdesktop** is being run on there exists a directory **TestRDP** in which **rdesktop** is called which contains a file **test.bat** that creates another file for testing purposes:

**test.bat**:

```
@ECHO OFF

echo "Test test test" > test_output_file.txt
```

Now, shouldn't file **test_output_file.txt** be created on the machine on which **rdesktop** has been called in directory **TestRDP**?

The linux machines are both running debian and the remote desktop machine Windows 7.

Comment: It seems to me that the [rdesktop -s](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdesktop) flag says "execute this on the remote (Windows) side"

Comment: I tried variations using -s "cmd.exe", -s "echo test", -s "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" but none worked.

Comment: It seems to me that if you want the output file to be local, you would have the batch file simply echo stuff to the screen, then redirect rdesktop's output to a local file.

Comment: It appears that I cannot launch any command using the -s parameter. Is there another way of running commands through rdesktop? When I run it with -s "cmd.exe", -s "echo test", -s "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" nothing happens. rdesktop logs in and nothing else happens.